# Sum a column multiple times based on different requirements from another column in one select statement?

Tags: php, mysql, select, sum

I want to sum the invoices based on the state column.
But i dont want to do 50 select statements. and the amount of states I query could vary
My Table

```
|invoice|state|
| 123   | NY  |
| 241   | VA  |
| 533   | WA  |
```

Can I do something like this:

```
$sql="Select SUM(invoice) where state=NY as NY AND where state=VA as VA";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ny,$va);
$stmt->fetch();
echo $ny;
echo $va;
//result: 123 241
```

Any ideas would be great! Do I have to make a select statement that executes in a for loop for each state in the array?
thanks!

Comment: Give us some data example.. table structure and a few rows of data

Comment: just added, hows that?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` for get sum by state wise.
Like

```
Select state,SUM(invoice) as Total FROM table_name GROUP BY state
```

It will give you SUM on invoices by state wise.
May be this will help you.

Comment: how can i loop through the results so i can use each states sum as a variable?

Comment: For this you need to foreach after get result of query.

Comment: what would the foreach loop be? what variable do I loop through?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you were looking for something like this?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN state='NY' THEN Invoice ELSE 0 END) AS 'NY',
       SUM(CASE WHEN state='VA' THEN Invoice ELSE 0 END) AS 'VA',
       SUM(CASE WHEN state='WA' THEN Invoice ELSE 0 END) AS 'WA' 
FROM table_name;
```

This will give you result like:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| NY  | VA  | WA  |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 123 | 241 | 533 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

If this is not the result you are looking for, you can add more details to your question like your expected output etc.